# Dynamic Programming Problem

Tags: c++, c, dynamic-programming

I am just unable to get the hang of dp. I know what I've to do but am just unable to implement it.E.g this practice problem from 'Codechef'

http://www.codechef.com/problems/MIXTURES/

If i consider the min smoke for mixtures i to j as m[i,j]

then

```
for k<- i to j 
m[i,j]=min(m[i,k]+m[k+1,j]+cost of mixing the resulting mixtures)
```

Is this correct? 
and how do I keep updating the colors of the mixtures for diff k and then revert back to original for the next k?

Comment: Since you are trying to learn, it may help if you explained what you expect to be happening (the algorithm, in English), as there are many things missing, such as the mod 100 part of the problem, so reading the problem, then your solution, there is too much missing here to try to solve the problem.

Comment: I am trying to find the optimal point to split the mixtures at every stage.As for the mod 100 part,I was confused earlier but thanks to deinst's answer i think i need to sum all the colors in the range [i,j] and then take mod by 100 for the resultant color of that range.
Is it the correct approach?

Comment: Yep, or you can keep track of them as you build your matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track.

The color of m[i,j] does not depend on the order of the mixtures.